# Configure SFTP server on Ubuntu to work with PhpStorm remote access

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, phpstorm, openssh

I am accessing my Ubuntu machine through VPN (PPTP) with ssh and I installed on this machine `openssh-server`. I would like to configure my PhpStorm 7.1.3 from my Windows 8.1 machine so I can access files on my remote Ubuntu server. I am trying to create `New project from existing files...`. I am configure SFTP that works (PhpStorm can connect) but when I finish setting new project the PhpStorm won't download remote files. It is logging in, than collecting data and than nothing else. I also tried to download remote files manually by clicking `Tools` > `Deployment` > `Download from remote` but nothing happened.

Is there anything that I need to set in my `openssh-server` (the settings are default)? I also tried to log in as root but it didn't help. PhpStorm can see remote files (when I chose `Project root`, `Resource root` and so on) but it can't download them.

Thanks for any useful help or information in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there is a bug in New project wizard -- sometimes it cannot finish when creating project from remote files. I suggest to create empty local project, configure remote server (Settings | Deployment), mark it as Default for this project and then download all necessary files manually via Remote Host tool window.

Comment: Meantime I tried something like this http://yetanothercomputingblog.blogspot.sk/2012/05/ubuntu-setup-sftp-server.html and it doesn't work so I tried to revert changes - uninstall openssh-server (purge) and than reinstall it, remove user and group and so on... But now when I am trying to connect via PhpStorm I am getting `HEAD method failed for "..." with HTTP status 403`. When I resolve this issue I will try your procedure.

Comment: @LazyOne Copy from Remote Host tool and Paste to Project structure worked. I am trying to copy symfony project and this process copied only `/web` folder. File transfer console said: "Failed to download /root/of/my/project", "Errors occured while collectiong files." and "Download items...". Could you help me resolve this issue as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in) for exception details - it should give you some clues. You can also set "Detailed" reporting in `Settings | Deployment | Options` to see what files have failed to download. But the reasons could be different: not enough rights, some glitch (try again) etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LazyOne proposed I added my files manually via `Remote Host tool` found in `View > Tool Windows > Remote Host`. I was setting up Symfony2 project and while I have bad mappings in `Deployment` settings it didn't working.

So for Symfony2 the mappings (`Deployment > your web deployment settings > tab Mappings`) are as follows:

Local path: your/local/path
Deployment path on server: /
Web path on server: /web

After correcting my mappings I was able to synchronize/upload/download files via Remote Host window.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my reputation doesn't allow me to write a comment so I'm posting an answer. If the answer above doesn't help, try to fix sshd_config

```
UsePAM yes
PermitUserEnvironment yes
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

It helpmed me like a magic. And it's source is here:
http://docs.midvision.com/LATEST/rapiddeploy-remoting/transport/jsch/issues.html